# SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing an android app in b4a and connecting to my web server by a php file. The app was OK until I changed my web host and now i have this error in my code when I run sql command. The phonenumber, code, time, and date are varchar. I even tested as int but no luck.

> INSERT INTO `TempCodes`(`ID`, `PhoneNumber`, `Code`, `Time`, `Date`)
>   VALUES (Null, \'9219142132\', \'835677\', \' 23:09:23 \', \'
>   2019/03/28 \')\nYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '\'9219142132\', \'835677\', \' 23:09:23 \', \' 2019/03/28
>   \')' at line 1

This is my sql command:

```
"INSERT INTO `TempCodes`(`ID`, `PhoneNumber`, `Code`, `Time`, `Date`) VALUES (Null, '" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "', '" & TempCode & "', '" & xTime & "', '" & xDate & "')"
```

I also removed " ` " from my variables and still nothing!

```
$databasehost = "host";
$databasename = "databse";
$databaseusername ="user";
$databasepassword = "pass";

$con = mysqli_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword, $databasename);// or die(mysqli_error($con));

error_reporting(0);

mysqli_set_charset ($con , "utf8");
//$query = file_get_contents("php://input");

// $query = $mcrypt->decrypt($query);
$sth = mysqli_query($con, $query);

//echo $query;

if (mysqli_errno($con)) {
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
echo $query.'\n';
echo mysqli_error($con);
}
else
{
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
$res = json_encode($rows);
echo $res;
mysqli_free_result($sth);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

this is the php code i use

i am in deep trouble here, please help !!!!

Comment: REmove the escape chars they are not required

Comment: `var_dump($query);` will immediately show you that your SQL is wrong. By the way, I don't know what language your SQL was built in but I know for a fact that you do not have PHP code concatenating those variables. Why the heck is it in dot notation?

Comment: Where do you set `$query` to the query?

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is probably some contrived include file heck-hole...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus :) Looks to me like the query is built in Basic and getting messed with in transit to the PHP

Comment: What is `& txtPhoneNumber.Text &` written in? That's not PHP.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus my SQL is in Unicode  and it was completely fine before i changed my web host ! and for the php, i found it in b4x.com honestly i don't understand most of it but it was working fine !

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks but that didn't work ! actually it worked but nothing came back ! just empty !

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert on ID field a NULL value.
Assume the TempCodes's table has the ID field AUTO_INCREMENT,thus the sentence should look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO `TempCodes`(`PhoneNumber`, `Code`, `Time`, `Date`) VALUES ('" 
 & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "', '" & TempCode & "', '" & xTime & "', '" & xDate & "')"
```